# Deleting upper left triangle from multiplication table

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops, nested-for-loop

I'm new to programming and am taking an intro to programming class which focuses on java.

I have an assignment that have been working on but can't seem to get the last portion of the requirements.

I am creating a source code that takes an input value, a, and creates a multiplication table a x a.

So far I have:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm5LD.png)

The end product should look something like the image. I feel like the next step is adding a new variable that prints the maxnum variable in the end of the first iteration and leaves whitespace in front of the rest of that iteration. I'm having trouble determining how to do it though. I feel like I need another for statement but don't know where to place it. My initial guess is after the for statement that uses the variable j but haven't had much luck. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you all!

What I have so far:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultiTable {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in =new Scanner(System. in );
    System.out.printf("%s", "Please enter a positive max. number: ");
    int maxnum = in.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("\n");
    while (maxnum < 0) {
      System.out.printf("%s" + "\n" + "\n", "Please enter a positive max. number: ");
      maxnum = in.nextInt();
    }
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    int k;
    System.out.printf("%10d", i);
    for (i = 0; i <= maxnum - 1; i++) {
      System.out.printf("%5d", i + 1);
    }
    System.out.printf("\n" + "-----");
    for (i = 0; i <= maxnum; i++) {
      System.out.printf("-----");
    }
    System.out.printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= maxnum; i++) {
      System.out.printf("%3d" + "%2s", i, " |");
      for (j = 0; j <= maxnum; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%5d", i * j);
      }
      System.out.printf("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkwQZ.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't describe your code. Post it here instead, as a [example]. Also please *show* the output you expect and what you're getting instead with your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

If you carefully look at the pattern, you'll see the indices in the lower right triangle conforms to the condition `max_count <= row + column`.

So accordingly you'll need to add a condition in the inner loop to print the numbers only if the condition satisfies.

```java
if(maxnum <= i+j) {
    System.out.printf("%5d", i * j);
} else {
    System.out.printf("%5s", " ");
}
```

Comment: Damn, this was it. Thank You, I been trying forever with for loops but this made it a lot easier!  Appreciate you

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you were trying to do ? [multiplication table triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJFvS.png)

For this result, you can use two "for" loops in replacement of your last loop ^^ :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= maxnum; i++){
        System.out.printf("%3d"+"%2s", i, " |");
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            System.out.printf(" ".repeat(5));
        }
        for (int j = i; j <= maxnum; j++){
            System.out.printf("%5d", i*j);
        }
        System.out.printf("\n"); 
    }
```

I hope it'll help you !

Comment: A little bit, I wanted it the values to be in the empty spaces instead of where the numbers are. So like inverted. This definitely helps though, thank you!